# Does the whitelist-source-range annotation work when using traefik ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I was wondering if [Kubernetes Ingress annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/docs/annotations.md) like `whitelist-source-range` would work when using the Traefik ingress controller instead of one of the implementations provided by Kubernetes like nginx or haproxy.
The [Kubernetes documentation says](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/docs/annotations.md):

> Traefik in particular defines several of its own annotations which are not described here, and does not seem to support any of the standard annotations.

But [this PR](https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/1332) in the Traefik project seems to add exactly that feature.

Is the kubernetes documentation wrong about Traefik not supporting the `whitelist-source-range` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you cite is correct, though not for long anymore: The PR targets the 1.4 milestone / version of Traefik which we plan to release approximately some time in the first half of September. Once the new version gets shipped, support for IP white-listing will become available.

If you're feeling impatient and adventurous at the same time, you can download the Docker image at `containous/traefik:experimental` and try the latest successful master build. For the slightly less impatient and adventurous, the first release candidate of version 1.4 (to be released shortly after the code freeze next week) is going to deliver the desired feature as well.